# SwiftUI: How can I adjust the circle Slider/Picker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to enable values to be entered using a Circle Slider. Before that I had implemented the Input of values with a Picker. But now I have a little Problem with the Circle Slider. I want to adjust the values that can be selected. Now I can select values from 0% to 100%. How can I display the values from 21% to 90% but from 50% the values should appear in „10 steps“. (21%,22%,23%… 50%, 60%, 70%, 80%, 90%) Is it possible to set the starting value to 32?

The Code from the new Circle Slider:

```
struct Slider: View {
    
    @State var size = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100
    @State var progress: CGFloat = 0
    @State var angle: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color("CircleSlider"), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 55, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .frame(width: size, height: size)
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: progress)
                    .stroke(Color("CircleSliderfill"), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 55, lineCap: .butt))
                    .frame(width: size, height: size)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color("CircleSlider"))
                    .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
                    .offset(x: size / 2)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
                    .offset(x: size / 2)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: angle))
                    .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged(onDrag(value:)))
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                
                //example from 0 to 100%
                Text(String(format: "%.0f", progress * 100) + "%")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onDrag(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        let vector = CGVector(dx: value.location.x, dy: value.location.y)
        let radians = atan2(vector.dy - 27.5, vector.dx - 27.5
        var angle = radians * 180 / .pi
        
        if angle < 0 {
            angle = 360 + angle
        }
        
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.15)) {
            
            let progress = angle / 360
            self.progress = progress
            self.angle = Double(angle)
        }
    }
}
```

The Code from the old Picker:

```
struct ValueO2: View {
    @State var valueIndexO2MOD_0 = 32
    @State var valueArray : [Int] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Section {
                Text("O2"))
                Picker("",selection: $valueIndexO2MOD_0) {
                    ForEach(valueArray, id: \.self){ value in
                        Text("\(value) %")
                    }
                }
            }
            .labelsHidden()
        }.onAppear{
            self.initPickerIndex()
        }
    }
           func initPickerIndex(){
               
               valueArray = []
               
               for index1 in 21..<50 {
                   valueArray.append(index1)
               }
                          
               for index2 in 1...5{
                   valueArray.append(40 + index2 * 10)
               }
           }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with some simple modifications:

If you want to change the Text in "10 steps" you can do this:

```
Text(String(format: "%.0f", progress >= 0.5 ? round(progress * 10) * 10 : progress * 100) + "%")
```

To change the actual value in "10 steps", you need to change the calculation of your progress and angle slightly:

```
func onDrag(value: DragGesture.Value) {
    let vector = CGVector(dx: value.location.x, dy: value.location.y)
    let radians = atan2(vector.dy - 27.5, vector.dx - 27.5)
    var angle = radians * 180 / .pi
    
    if angle < 0 {
        angle = 360 + angle
    }
    
    var progress = angle / 360
    
    if progress >= 0.5 {
        // Round & update angle
        progress = round(progress * 10) / 10
        angle = progress * 360
    }
    
    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.15)) {
        self.progress = progress
        self.angle = Double(angle)
    }
}
```

To set a **start value** you can use a simple function:

```
func setStartValue(value: CGFloat) {
    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.15)) {
        progress = value
        angle = Double(progress * 360)
    }
}
```

You can call it when the view appears by using the `.onAppear` modifier:

```
VStack {
        // your slider
    }.onAppear {
        setStartValue(value: 0.32)
    }
```

**EDIT: Limit range from 21% to 90%**

```
func onDrag(value: DragGesture.Value) {
    let vector = CGVector(dx: value.location.x, dy: value.location.y)
    let radians = atan2(vector.dy - 27.5, vector.dx - 27.5)
    var angle = radians * 180 / .pi
    
    if angle < 0 {
        angle = 360 + angle
    }
    
    var progress = angle / 360
    
    // "10 Steps"
    if progress >= 0.5 {
        // Round & update angle
        progress = round(progress * 10) / 10
        angle = progress * 360
    }
    
    // Boundaries (21% to 90%)
    let minValue: CGFloat = 0.21
    let maxValue: CGFloat = 0.9
    
    if progress < minValue {
        progress = minValue
        angle = progress * 360
    } else if progress > maxValue {
        progress = maxValue
        angle = progress * 360
    }
    
    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.15)) {
        self.progress = progress
        self.angle = Double(angle)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I changed the calculation of my progress and angle not directly in the Text field. But the slider has a range from 0% to 100%. I need it from 21% to 90%. Is this possible? The "10 steps" and the start value works well! Do you know whether the variable "progress" can be duplicated in a new variable which is then an Int (e.g. not 0.32 rather 32)? I need this later for another calculation.

Comment: You're welcome! I edited my answer to limit the range from 21% to 90%. Is it working as you expected?

Comment: @lula08 But I'm not quite sure what you mean by "duplicating". Of course you can create another variable to copy the value of progress (`var newProgress = Int(progress * 100)`). But I'm not sure why you want to do that. I would personally just use the existing multiplied with 100... But feel free to specify your use case and I will try to help you.

Comment: Thank you again! Yes it works! One little thing would be cool that the "full circle" can be used. So that the start position is 0 = 21% and the end position 1 = 90%. I don't know how to solve this now, but maybe I can do it later. With another input, the circle should not go from 21% to 90% but the selection option should be "1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6" (double). Is that the same procedure as before? In the case of the old picker, I had solved this with an array. Do I have to do that too? Sorry for all the questions, but I'm new in Swift/ SwiftUI :)

Comment: The selected variable is should be transferred to a "Calculation Kit" with calculation functions in a separate File. And the functions in the "Calculation Kit" require an Int, but the slider only gives a CGFloat

Comment: I think it's not that easy to get the full circle working. Probably you could create some kind of linear equation that translates the progress into a range between 21-90. To get the double values I would use `(round(progress * 10) / 10) + 1`. That way you can translate e.g. 0.53 to 1.5

Comment: Okay I unterstand. Can You show me how can I do it from 1.2 to 1.6? I try it with (round(progress * 10) / 10) + 1 but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: I posted a second answer with the code needed to do this. It actually solves both of your questions. Cause you can select numbers between 21 and 90 by providing an array with this range. But you can also provide an array with "1.2, 1.3, ...".

Comment: Yes perfect! Thank you for all. Thats helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the idea of selecting elements from an array using the slider is interesting. So here is a second answer how this can be achieved:

```
    struct CircularSlider: View {
    
    @State var size = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100
    @State var progress: CGFloat = 0
    @State var angle: Double = 0
    
    let validValues = Array(21...90) // [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6]
    @State var selectedValue: Double = 31
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color(.lightGray), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 55, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
                    .frame(width: size, height: size)
                
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: progress)
                    .stroke(Color(.systemGreen), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 55, lineCap: .butt))
                    .frame(width: size, height: size)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color(.lightGray))
                    .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
                    .offset(x: size / 2)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
                    .offset(x: size / 2)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: angle))
                    .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged(onDrag(value:)))
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                
                // Text(String(format: "%.1f", selectedValue))
                Text("\(selectedValue)")
                
            }
        }.onAppear {
            setStartValue(value: selectedValue)
        }
    }
    
    private func onDrag(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        let vector = CGVector(dx: value.location.x, dy: value.location.y)
        let radians = atan2(vector.dy - 27.5, vector.dx - 27.5)
        var angle = radians * 180 / .pi
        
        if angle < 0 {
            angle = 360 + angle
        }
        
        let progress = angle / 360
        
        // Select Value in Array
        selectValue(progress: progress)
        
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.15)) {
            self.progress = progress
            self.angle = Double(angle)
        }
    }
    
    private func selectValue(progress: CGFloat) {
        let segments: CGFloat = CGFloat(validValues.count - 1)
        let indexLimit: CGFloat = 100 / segments
        let index = Int(round((progress / indexLimit) * 100))
        selectedValue = Double(validValues[index])
    }
    
    private func setStartValue(value: Double) {
        
        // Transform value to progress
        if let index = validValues.firstIndex(of: Int(value)) {
            progress = CGFloat(index) / CGFloat(validValues.count)
            print(progress)
            
            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.15)) {
                self.progress = CGFloat(progress)
                self.angle = Double(self.progress * 360)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```